# Is there a way to have DebugDiag2 output a report formatted as text only?

Tags: debugdiag, debug-diagnostic-tool

The report produced by DebugDiag2 is formatted as HTML but it does not look possible to read using just a text editor. I recently analyzed a process dump that produced a report that crashes any browser i open it with (IE, Edge, Chrome). Is there a way to have DebugDiag2 output a report formatted as text only?